# Is there a tool like doxygen for XSLT?

Tags: xslt, doxygen

Does someone know a tool, that can extract the code structure from undocumented xsl files?

I know there is XSLTdoc, which can extract documentation elements from xsl files to build html reference pages. But for undocumented xsl files, XSLTdoc's output is rather useless.

Doxygen is able to produce valuable output even if the code is not documented. Does there exist a comparable tool for xsl?

The best I found so far is [depgraph](http://www.thoughtcrime.us/software/xslt-dependency-graph/), this little stylesheet produces a dependency graph for includes and imports.

What I am looking for is a call-graph generator for xsl templates.

Comment: How would it work? The except for when calling named templates, how would a static tool know that `<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>` calls `<xsl:template match="abc">...</xsl:template>`?

Answer (score 1):

I find [Oxygen XML Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) very useful for everything XML / XSL / XSD related; it can generate XML structure from both XSL and XSD and have a good attempt at building XSL and XSD from an XML document. It isn't free however but a trial is available.

Answer (score 0):

Have look to [xdc](http://xdc.sourceforge.net/) (open source), it seems very promising. See also this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293252/is-there-guidelines-to-document-xsl-stylesheets/19299600?noredirect=1#19299600
Regards